# I am having trouble finding the average sales of all shops

Tags: sql, sql-server

I can't seem to find a solution on how to receive the sales of the shops that are bigger than the average of all shops.

I have already tried some ways and managed to get the average sales of each shop. I have then tried to get the shops that have sales bigger than the average of all shops but have failed.

```
SELECT SALES, (SELECT AVG(AVERSALES * SALES)) AS AVGSALES  FROM 
(
    SELECT           
        Shops.NAME, 
        SUM(InvDet.QTY * Products.PRICE ) AS SALES, 
        AVG(InvDet.QTY * Products.PRICE) AS AVERSALES
    FROM              
        Invoices 
        INNER JOIN InvDet ON Invoices.INV_ID = InvDet.INV_ID
        INNER JOIN Products ON InvDet.PR_ID = Products.PR_ID
        INNER JOIN Shops  ON Shops.S_ID=Invoices.S_ID
    WHERE 
    Invoices.INVOICE_DATE BETWEEN '2013-06-24' AND '2013-06-30'
    GROUP BY     Shops.NAME
)AS SALES_TABLE
GROUP BY SALES
HAVING  SALES > (SELECT AVG(AVERSALES))
```

Comment: Can you provide sample test data

Comment: @saravanatn samples of the data from my tables? or from the results of the execution?

Comment: from table and expected results as well

Comment: shop table: S_ID, NAME nvarchar(255),
invoice details table: P_ID, QTY, INV_ID,
invoices table: INV_ID, S_ID, INVOICE_DATE,
products table: PR_ID, PRODUCT_NAME, PRICE.
Results from the example above: 
SALES    AVGSALES
112.65 2115.00375
201.82 6788.55206666667
444.81 16487.994675

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have many ways to get what you are looking for.
One of them should be this:

```
select
  s.name,
  s.SALES
from (
  select 
    s.name,
    sum(i.QTY * p.PRICE) AS SALES
  from Invoices i 
    join InvDet id ON i.INV_ID = id.INV_ID
    join Products p ON id.PR_ID = p.PR_ID
    join Shops s ON s.S_ID=i.S_ID 
  where i.INVOICE_DATE BETWEEN '2013-06-24' AND '2013-06-30'
  group by s.name
  ) s
  join (
    select avg(i.QTY * p.PRICE) as average
    from Invoices i
      join InvDet id ON i.INV_ID = id.INV_ID
      join Products p ON id.PR_ID = p.PR_ID
    -- If you want to compare with the total average 
    -- remove this where part
    where i.INVOICE_DATE BETWEEN '2013-06-24' AND '2013-06-30'
  ) a
    on s.SALES>a.average
```

This other approach (for me clearer) must return the same:

```
declare @average float

select @average=avg(i.QTY * p.PRICE)
from Invoices i
  join InvDet id ON i.INV_ID = id.INV_ID
  join Products p ON id.PR_ID = p.PR_ID
-- If you want to compare with the total average 
-- remove this where part
where i.INVOICE_DATE BETWEEN '2013-06-24' AND '2013-06-30'

select 
  s.name,
  sum(i.QTY * p.PRICE) AS SALES
from Invoices i 
  join InvDet id ON i.INV_ID = id.INV_ID
  join Products p ON id.PR_ID = p.PR_ID
  join Shops s ON s.S_ID=i.S_ID 
where i.INVOICE_DATE BETWEEN '2013-06-24' AND '2013-06-30'
group by s.name
having sum(i.QTY * p.PRICE)>@average
```

There are other choices (for example a common table expression would fit well here too). I think with these two is enough to solve your question. I hope they fit with what you need.

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure about your requirement

```
SELECT SALES, (SELECT AVG(AVERSALES * SALES)) AS AVGSALES  FROM 
    (
        SELECT           
            Shops.NAME, 
            SUM(InvDet.QTY * Products.PRICE ) AS SALES, 
            AVG(InvDet.QTY * Products.PRICE) AS AVERSALES
        FROM              
            Invoices 
            INNER JOIN InvDet ON Invoices.INV_ID = InvDet.INV_ID
            INNER JOIN Products ON InvDet.PR_ID = Products.PR_ID
            INNER JOIN Shops  ON Shops.S_ID=Invoices.S_ID
        WHERE 
        Invoices.INVOICE_DATE BETWEEN '2013-06-24' AND '2013-06-30'
        GROUP BY     Shops.NAME
    )AS SALES_TABLE
    GROUP BY SALES
    HAVING  SALES > AVERSALES
```

Comment: this query has to show the shops with sales above average sales in a specific period

Comment: This makes no sense. I don’t know the point to group by sales. Sales is a metric, not a dimension.